# Can boost do shared memory between processes that are on different CPUs

Tags: c++, boost, multiprocessing, boost-interprocess

If i have a multiprocessor with 2 CPUs, and i have a process running on CPU 1, and another process on CPU 2, is boost::interprocess shared memory be used between them? If so, how is that implemented? I couldn't find any documentation in the [boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you're on either an SMP or standard NUMA system.

Maybe not if some of your CPUs are running on daughter boards or similar.

---

The OS and underlying hardware platform (which you haven't told us) control this, and you should be able to ask a question specific to that OS/platform in an appropriate forum if you're still not sure.

If you're not sure which of the above two cases are relevant, it's almost certain you're on a general-purpose platform and it will all work. Note that Boost may not expose NUMA affinity control however, if you want to choose which node pages are allocated on.

Comment: thanks for getting me pointed in the right direction; this is all very new for me and i just wasnt really sure where to even begin looking, so this gives me a good start to go do more investigating on my own

Answer (score 1):

It is not advantage of boost, but platform. Boost uses [shmem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHMEM) or [memory mapped files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) support in the level of operating system.

Comment: How would i be able to tell if the two CPUs have support for shmem?